# VBA Macro - ActiveDocument.Range - "Invalid use of property" issue

Tags: vba, ms-word

Years ago I wrote the following VBA Macro in order to find and highlight specific words in MS Office Word documents:

```
Sub HighlightWords()
    With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        File = .OpenTextFile("C:\Users\...\words_list.txt", 1).ReadAll
    End With
    List = Split(File, vbCrLf)
    For Each Target In List
        Set Range = ActiveDocument.Range
        With Range.Find
            .Text = Target
            .Format = False
            .MatchCase = False
            .MatchWholeWord = True
            .MatchWildcards = False
            .MatchSoundsLike = False
            .MatchAllWordForms = False
            Do While .Execute(Forward:=True) = True
                Range.HighlightColorIndex = wdYellow
            Loop
        End With
    Next
End Sub
```

It worked perfectly in MS Office Word 2007 (on Windows Vista). But now it doesn't work in MS Office Word 2021 (on Windows 11). In the VBA Editor, I get the following error prompt:

"Invalid use of property" related to "Set Range = ActiveDocument.Range".

How can I fix it?

Comment: You're trying to use a variable named "Range" - that is a reserved keyword for the variable type `Range`. Try `Dim MyRange As Range` and then `Set MyRange = ActiveDocument.Range`

Comment: If **it is at least a document open in Word** you do not need the `Range` variable, which as stated above may be confusing for VBA. And for you, in case of debugging need. Delete that code line and simple use `With ActiveDocument.Range.Find` instead of `With Range.Find`...

Comment: @FaneDuru I've tried with `With ActiveDocument.Range.Find`, but I get this error: Path could not be found. That's the only thing I changed.

Comment: @PeterT Same error.

Comment: Do you run this code on Word Application, or try an automation from a different one? If Word, as I asked in my first comment, **are there any document open**? Please, place in your code, as its first line, the next debugging code line `MsgBox ActiveDocument.Name`. Does it return anything or raises an error?

Comment: I run the code on Word, with one document opened. The debugging code you suggested returns the name of that document.

Comment: Have you verified that the path to the file "words_list.txt" is exactly as the same as it is specified in the code? That is the only part of your code that could give a path not found error.

Comment: The path to "words_list.txt" is correct. What I don't understand is why that code - exactly the same - worked in MS Office Word 2007, but now doesn't work in MS Office Word 2021.